# Issue with add method in tensorflow : AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

```
import keras as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow import set_random_seed

for hidden_neuron in hidden_neurons:
  model = Sequential()
```

`model.add(Dense(hidden_neuron, input_dim=61, activation='relu'))`

-> i am getting error at this line. I am not really sure what am i missing here.

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "PycharmProjects/HW2/venv/bin/hw3q4.py", line 46, in 
>       model.add(Dense(hidden_neuron, input_dim=61, activation='relu'))   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py",
>   line 165, in add
>       layer(x)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 414, in **call**
>       self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py",
>   line 279, in assert_input_compatibility
>       K.is_keras_tensor(x)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 472, in is_keras_tensor
>       if not is_tensor(x):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 480, in is_tensor
>       return isinstance(x, tf_ops._TensorLike) or tf_ops.is_dense_tensor_like(x)
>   **AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops' has no attribute '_TensorLike'**

Answer (score 56):

For me, the fix was importing

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
```

instead of

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
```

There seems to be some weird compatibility issues between keras and tensorflow.keras

Comment: Why not sync tf and keras and import properly from keras?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following import command:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ...
```

instead of the '*old*' one:

```
from keras.layers import ....
```

As described [here.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/6177)

Comment: Great! You made my day!

Answer (score 4):

For those who stumbled on to this, reinstalling Keras and Tensorflow fixes the issue.

Comment: Actually, that is not entirely true. It depends on the combination of keras and tensorflow versions as `keras` was integrated into tf as `tensorflow.keras`. Nevertheless you could get lucky by updating.

Answer (score 4):

It is due to version incompatibility.
Update *keras* to the latest version compatible with *tensorflow*:

```
pip install --upgrade keras==x.x.x
```

Answer (score 4):

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow 
!pip install tensorflow==1.14

!pip uninstall keras 
!pip install keras==2.2.4
```

Installing the above versions of keras and tensorflow have solved the problem for me.

Comment: Can't find that version of tensorflow available anymore (only from 2.2.0 onwards via pip)

Answer (score 1):

Simply updating both TensorFlow as well as Keras might fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you are importing the preliminaries.
If importing tensorflow as tf and importing keras within the tensorflow, you should start with tf.keras. otherwise, if you are importing directly keras.models then you can just start off with Input() or Conv().

Answer (score 0):

Many people saying about updating TensorFlow or Keras, which is a good solution but in a few cases it might not be applicable, (depends on the situation).
The idea of uninstalling and re-installing Keras and Tensorflow, by installing first TensorFlow, is one of the approaches that can solve the issue.
For the ones that have the problem in Jupyter notebook, you may wish to close and reopen your Jupyter notebook, when you have installed the libraries, because sometimes it doesn't update properly.